# Entering values in the array with sqlite3_step

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have this code that saves the records within an array:

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {

NSString *stringTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ WHERE id = ?",table];

const char *sql = [stringTable UTF8String];

sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, sql, -1, &statement2, NULL);
sqlite3_bind_int(statement2, 1, value);

while (sqlite3_step(statement2) == SQLITE_ROW){

[arrayValues addObject:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, 1)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, 1)] : @""];

[arrayValues addObject:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, 2)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, 2)] : @""];

        ...
        ...

[arrayValues addObject:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, 21)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, 21)] : @""];

              }
}
```

All I'm trying to do is find a way to automate this code and keep me a lot of time typing command repeated, for that, I tried to create an int and increase with while:

```
int temp = 1;//If 0 he get ID and I don't like to get...
...
while (sqlite3_step(statement2) == SQLITE_ROW){

            [arrayValues addObject:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, temp)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, temp)] : @""];

            temp++;

        }     
    }
```

But this method return only one object (that is the row 1), why this is happening, and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your loop *inside* the `while` loop:

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement2) == SQLITE_ROW){
    for (int temp = 1: temp <= 21; temp++) {
        [arrayValues addObject:((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, temp)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String: (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement2, temp)] : @""];
    }     
}
```